# How do I connect to the free cyren.com - API with R?

Tags: r, post, get, httr

I want to connect to the Cyren API via R.
[Link](https://help.cyren.com/display/CULA/Using+the+API)

But I can't make it work.Does anyone maybe have some experience with it?

Here is a reproducable code:

```
library(httr)
a <- POST(url = "https://api-url.cyren.com/api/v1/free/url",
          body='"data":[{"url":"test.com"}]',
          encode = 'json',
          config = list(add_headers(Authorization ='Bearer my.JWT.token',
                                    'Content-Type' = 'application/json')
          )
)

a
```

Expected output:
`{"url":"test.com","categoryNames": ["Computers & Technology"]}`

But I always get the Status 401 (unautorized).

Comment: Have you tried `POST(url=, body=, encode=, add_headers(Authorization='...', 'Content-Type'='..'))`? That is, remove the `config=list(.)` wrapping `add_headers`.

Comment: Thanks!
If I do that, I get 400 (Bad Request)
`POST(url = "https://api-url.cyren.com/api/v1/free/url",
          body='"data":[{"url":"test.com"}]',
          encode = 'json',
          add_headers(Authorization ='Bearer my.JWT.token',
                                    'Content-Type' = 'application/json')
)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out.

```
a <- POST(url = "https://api-url.cyren.com/api/v1/free/url",
      body='{"url":"cyren.com"}',
      encode = 'json',
      config = add_headers(Authorization= 'Bearer my.JWT.token'
                                ,'Content-Type' = 'application/json'
      )
```

)